# I want to mark as true if date was within last 12 months

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbt

This is what I have done; I am not sure if this is valid and will bring in the outcome that I want

```
case when lost_renewal_start_date between getdate() and dateadd(day, -365, getdate())
     then true
     else false 
end as churned_within_last_12_months
```

Comment: Switch the order.  The earlier date needs to be first for the between to work.  (at least for most SQL engines)  `when lost_renewal_start_date between dateadd(day, -365, getdate()) and getdate() then true else false end as churned_within_last_12_months`  and are you sure you want that or use date add for a year to handle leap years...  edge cases... they can be really annoying

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select *,
       case when 
             lost_renewal_start_date > (current_date - interval '1 year')::date 
             and lost_renewal_start_date <= current_date 
             then true 
             else false
        end as churned_within_last_12_months
from test
```

See a demo on Postgres from [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c2c80465c45d6f0557e7daf37fe00c33).